# How to convert CSV value in a cell to Rows and UnPivot it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to convert data in a table

```
Name    DependsOn-CSV
----    -------------
a       b,c
b       d
c
d
e       g
f       b,e,a,g
g
h       a
```

to

```
Name    DependsOn-Rows
----    --------------
a       b
a       C
b       d
c
d
e       g
f       b
f       e
f       a
f       g
g
h       a
```

and then to

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
--  --  --  --  --
f
    b
        d
    e
        g
    a
        b
            d
        c
    g
h
    a
        b
            d
        c
```

using SQL (not usnig TSQL/loops etc). Can this be done?

---

UPDATE: I am thinking from a relational perspective. So please do not use XML, OpenQuery, etc. for the first part of the question. There is a relational design related problem here in the question and thats what is the challenge!

Comment: What is the logic of getting the last table?

Comment: @Igor: Most likely it's a tree showing the dependencies. The column position corresponds to the hierarchy level of the nodes it contains. Every next row contains an item related to the current one in one of three ways: a child, a sibling, a sibling of one of the parents. The OP should clarify that, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the first result by doing this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),DependsOnCSV VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    ('a','b,c'),
    ('b','d'),
    ('c',''),
    ('d',''),
    ('e','g'),
    ('f','b,e,a,g'),
    ('g',''),
    ('h','a')
```

**Split function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(5)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

**Alternative split function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@s varchar(512),@sep char(1))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
GO
```

**The query**

```
SELECT
  tbl.Name,
  split.val AS [DependsOn-Rows]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(tbl.DependsOnCSV,',') split
```

Then I am not really sure how to get the second result. You have to explain more

Comment: Good stuff :)
Though I do not like xml manipulations as I was looking for an answer that was pure relational. Personally I believe that xml manipulations are as good as an OpenQuery() call. Truely appreciate your efforts, good job.

Comment: Apologies, on a second look, I think that you have solved the problem using the relational approach (CROSS APPLY). The function can be rewritten without using xml. Thanks..
Lets focus on the second part now..